# Cleared Gmail password by mistake

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I can't log into my Gmail account. I was trying to clear the cookies and I think I touched the wrong button. Now I can't access my account I am desperate to recover it quickly.

Comment: Have you forgotten your gmail password? Have you tried the "Can't access your account?" link on the gmail login page? Can you login to _any_ account? Have you accidentally _disabled_ cookies?!

Answer (score 2):

If you have forgotten your account's password, please use the [Google Accounts recovery tool](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery) to gain back access to your account.

> To reset your password:
>
> 1. Enter your Google Account email address on the [password assistance page](https://accounts.google.com/RecoverAccount?fpOnly=1&hl=en) and type the the words in the distorted picture.
> 2. Choose how to get back into your account.

[Source](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2943007?hl=en&ref_topic=3026306)